# Send Order Details through whatsapp using twilio and node js

Tags: twilio

I want to send order details through whatsApp message using twilio and node js. I could able to send order details to my number which is added in the sandbox. If I want to send order details message to user numbers, message is failed. How to do that?Please help me

```
import twilio from 'twilio';

export const sendOrder = async (order) => {
const accountSid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);
await client.messages
  .create({
     from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
     to: `whatsapp:+91${order.shippingAddress.phone}`,
     body: 'Order Amount...' + order.totalPrice,
  })
  .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the party you are trying to send a WhatsApp message to a member of your [Sandbox](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/sandbox) (did they send a message such as `join xyz`)?

Did you use one of the Sandbox example templates to send them the first message? You have to use a template when initiating outbound WhatsApp messages until they respond, more details [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/key-concepts#the-24-hour-window-or-24-hour-session).

You can check the Twilio [debugger](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021755854-Troubleshooting-Alerts-Debug-Events-and-Errors-on-Twilio-Voice-Calls) or the API response for errors.

Comment: no. Its an ecommerce app. when Order is placed, the order details are sent to their whatsapp number

Comment: Ok, so you will need to create a WhatsApp template and move off the Sandbox (which has join requirement) - https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/sandbox#twilio-sandbox-limitations.